# SELECT difference in 2 datetime columns WHERE interval

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals, datediff

I can't find a solution to this anywhere. All I want to do is subtract datetimecolumn1 from datetime column2, and only select those records where that interval > 1 day. I know this sounds simple, and probably is, but none of the datediff/interval WHERE's I've come up with have worked.

Comment: That is pretty simple, what have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: you can use date_diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF`.

```
SELECT *
    , DATEDIFF(datetimecolumn1, datetimecolumn2)
FROM youtable
WHERE DATEDIFF(datetimecolumn1, datetimecolumn2) > 1;
```

Comment: The answer is not complete. You must output the difference between two dates

Comment: Yes, the above answer is absolutely correct. I had been using a subtract sign in the parenthesis instead of a comma. That's what happens when you're working on a Saturday night, I suppose. Thanks people.